# WAF cors-origin-request

Tags: cross-domain, captcha, http-status-code-405, amazon-waf

Application is deployed in eks behind an application loadbalancer. Waf is attached to this alb. In waf action for rule AWS-AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList#HostingproviderIPlist is set as block and override to captcha.

We are doing a cross-origin-request with a VPN turned on and our request gets blocked. In the waf sample requests section we could see our IP  and rule as AWS-AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList#HostingproviderIPlist and action as captcha. But we didn't receive any captcha page to resolve.In the waf log we could see the reason as token missing
Attaching the screenshot of error page[image]

**WAF log**

> ```
>     "args": "",
>     "httpVersion": "HTTP/2.0",
>     "httpMethod": "OPTIONS",
>     "requestId": "1-6555fb65-77de024547288a803331d844"
> },
> "captchaResponse": {
>     "responseCode": 405,
>     "failureReason": "TOKEN_MISSING"
> },
> "ja3Fingerprint": "61f38b2663c769c4d33144835db7db15" }
> ```

**Har file**

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      "name": "WebInspector",
      "version": "537.36"
    },
    "pages": [],
    "entries": [
      {
        "_initiator": {
          "type": "script",
          "stack": {
            "callFrames": [
              {
                "functionName": "sendRequest",
                "scriptId": "7",
                "url": "https://retrogreen.co.uk/amt/test-cors.html",
                "lineNumber": 70,
                "columnNumber": 10
              },
              {
                "functionName": "onclick",
                "scriptId": "25",
                "url": "https://retrogreen.co.uk/amt/test-cors.html",
                "lineNumber": 78,
                "columnNumber": 34
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "_priority": "High",
        "_resourceType": "xhr",
        "cache": {},
        "request": {
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "https://api.retrogreen.co.uk/api/v1/property",
          "httpVersion": "",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "sec-ch-ua",
              "value": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"119\", \"Chromium\";v=\"119\", \"Not?A_Brand\";v=\"24\""
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "application/json"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "https://retrogreen.co.uk/"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
              "value": "?0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Authorization",
              "value": "Basic cmV0cm9HcmVlbjpTS3ZDTlJuVHB1RGdiVkg="
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-ch-ua-platform",
              "value": "\"Windows\""
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [],
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": 187,
          "postData": {
            "mimeType": "application/json",
            "text": "{\"postcode\":\"RG20 0PG\",\"uprn\":\"100062458026\",\"address1\":\"Magpies\",\"address2\":\"Gore End Road\",\"address3\":\"Ball Hill\",\"latitude\":\"51.3680464\",\"longitude\":\"-1.3990267\",\"manualAddress\":false}"
          }
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 0,
          "statusText": "",
          "httpVersion": "",
          "headers": [],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 0,
            "mimeType": "x-unknown"
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": -1,
          "_transferSize": 0,
          "_error": "net::ERR_FAILED"
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "",
        "startedDateTime": "2023-11-17T06:55:53.396Z",
        "time": 985.3649999859044,
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 985.3649999859044,
          "dns": -1,
          "ssl": -1,
          "connect": -1,
          "send": 0,
          "wait": 0,
          "receive": 0,
          "_blocked_queueing": -1
        }
      },
      {
        "_initiator": {
          "type": "preflight",
          "url": "https://api.retrogreen.co.uk/api/v1/property",
          "requestId": "23628.42"
        },
        "_priority": "High",
        "_resourceType": "preflight",
        "cache": {},
        "connection": "589586",
        "request": {
          "method": "OPTIONS",
          "url": "https://api.retrogreen.co.uk/api/v1/property",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": ":authority",
              "value": "api.retrogreen.co.uk"
            },
            {
              "name": ":method",
              "value": "OPTIONS"
            },
            {
              "name": ":path",
              "value": "/api/v1/property"
            },
            {
              "name": ":scheme",
              "value": "https"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept",
              "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-language",
              "value": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
            },
            {
              "name": "access-control-request-headers",
              "value": "authorization,content-type"
            },
            {
              "name": "access-control-request-method",
              "value": "POST"
            },
            {
              "name": "origin",
              "value": "https://retrogreen.co.uk"
            },
            {
              "name": "referer",
              "value": "https://retrogreen.co.uk/"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-fetch-dest",
              "value": "empty"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-fetch-mode",
              "value": "cors"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-fetch-site",
              "value": "same-site"
            },
            {
              "name": "user-agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [],
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 405,
          "statusText": "",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "cache-control",
              "value": "no-store, max-age=0"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-length",
              "value": "2453"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-type",
              "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            {
              "name": "date",
              "value": "Fri, 17 Nov 2023 06:55:18 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "server",
              "value": "awselb/2.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-amzn-waf-action",
              "value": "captcha"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 0,
            "mimeType": "text/html"
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": -1,
          "_transferSize": 0,
          "_error": null
        },
        "serverIPAddress": "52.208.205.231",
        "startedDateTime": "2023-11-17T06:55:53.399Z",
        "time": 980.6530000127032,
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 290.697,
          "dns": 0.012999999999976808,
          "ssl": 227.9219999999999,
          "connect": 455.302,
          "send": 0.19100000000003092,
          "wait": 233.29600000038272,
          "receive": 1.1540000123204663,
          "_blocked_queueing": -1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```